# display array string to listview in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

```
            String output_ktdk="";
            String outputjson = result.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


            String[] values = new String[] {
                    outputjson

                };
            final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
              list.add(values[i]);
            }
              ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

- Display listview : "abc","abc","abc" .....
- Help me ..............

cxcxccx

Comment: do you want we make your homework ? [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first parse outputjson by using JSONObject

Comment: you for your example is not . Thanks

Comment: I should to know what the content in "result" first

Comment: Hi . Thank Zhaokun . result = ["Android","Apple","amazon","View"] . help me

Comment: `String result = "[\"Android\",\"Apple\",\"amazon\",\"View\"]";`
`result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1);`
`String[] values = result.split(",");`
`for(int i=0; i<values.length; ++i){`
  `values[i] = values[i].substring(1, values[i].length() - 1);`
`}`